# Sort a pandas DataFrame by a column in another dataframe - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, series

Let's say I have a Pandas DataFrame with two columns, like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [100, 200, 300, 400]})
print(df)
```

---

```
   a    b
0  1  100
1  2  200
2  3  300
3  4  400
```

And let's say I also have a Pandas Series, like:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 3, 2, 4])
print(s)
```

---

```
0    1
1    3
2    2
3    4
dtype: int64
```

How can I sort the `a` column to become the same order as the `s` series, with the corresponding row values sorted together?

My desired output would be:

```
   a    b
0  1  100
1  3  300
2  2  200
3  4  400
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

**Please check self-answer below.**

Comment: Is series `s completely separate from dataframe `df`? Where does it come from? It makes things easier if you concat series `s` into `df`. Then you can simply do `df.sort_values('s')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have ran into these issues quite often, so I just thought to share my solutions in Pandas.

## Solutions:

**Solution 1:**

Using `set_index` to convert the `a` column to the index, then use `reindex` to change the order, then use `rename_axis` to change the index name back to `a`, then use `reset_index` to convert the `a` column from an index back to a column:

```
print(df.set_index('a').reindex(s).rename_axis('a').reset_index('a'))
```

**Solution 2:**

Using `set_index` to convert the `a` column to the index, then use `loc` to change the order, then use `reset_index` to convert the `a` column from an index back to a column:

```
print(df.set_index('a').loc[s].reset_index())
```

**Solution 3:**

Using `iloc` to index the rows in a different order, then use `map` to get that order that would fit the `df` to make it get sorted with the `s` series:

```
print(df.iloc[list(map(df['a'].tolist().index, s))])
```

**Solution 4:**

Using `pd.DataFrame` to create a new DataFrame object, then use `sorted` with a `key` argument to sort the DataFrame by the `s` series:

```
print(pd.DataFrame(sorted(df.values.tolist(), key=lambda x: s.tolist().index(x[0])), columns=df.columns))
```

## Timings:

Timing with the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
from timeit import timeit
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [100, 200, 300, 400]})
s = pd.Series([1, 3, 2, 4])
def u10_1():
    return df.set_index('a').reindex(s).rename_axis('a').reset_index('a')
def u10_2():
    return df.set_index('a').loc[s].reset_index()
def u10_3():
    return df.iloc[list(map(df['a'].tolist().index, s))]
def u10_4():
    return pd.DataFrame(sorted(df.values.tolist(), key=lambda x: s.tolist().index(x[0])), columns=df.columns)
print('u10_1:', timeit(u10_1, number=1000))
print('u10_2:', timeit(u10_2, number=1000))
print('u10_3:', timeit(u10_3, number=1000))
print('u10_4:', timeit(u10_4, number=1000))
```

Output:

```
u10_1: 3.012849470495621
u10_2: 3.072132612502147
u10_3: 0.7498072134665241
u10_4: 0.8109911930595484
```

@Allen has a pretty good answer too.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
(
    df.assign(s=s)
    .sort_values(by='s')
    .drop('s', axis=1)
)
```